# Software to detect deadlock for Windows

Tags: windows

I have an application sometimes freezes, and I believe that the threads are entering a deadlock state.

Is there a tool for Windows that monitors a given process, and detects thread deadlock?

Answer (score 1):

Two Microsoft tools come to mind.  I've used both to troubleshoot memory related problems and crashes, but, not a deadlock.  [ApplicationVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx) and [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) both state they can handle subtle programming issues including "hangs".  Both are relatively easy to use, but, you'll still need to read the help files to set up their usage.  Application Verifier works best if the application can be run under a debugger, but, it's not required.  DebugDiag can post process a dump file (.dmp) if you have one.  I'd suggest you take some time to investigate using one or both to debug your problem.

Comment: I wonder if Intel VTune can deal with this kind of problem...

Comment: I don't think so.  We use it mostly for performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a monitoring application... but if you have a deadlock in a **.NET** application, I found the combination of [WinDbg [Microsoft]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SOSex](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) helpful.

Usage isn't simple, you'll need debugging experience. The following commands might help getting started:

```
.symfix c:\symbols
.reload
.loadby sos clr; .loadby sos mscorwks
.load sosex
!dlk
```